# Python: improve in elegant way (code saving) a function in order to avoid several Statements

Tags: python, performance, optimization, if-statement

I wrote this function to read [Las](http://www.liblas.org/tutorial/python.html) file and save a shapefile. The function creates a shapefile with 8 fields. What i wish insert a **parse** element in the function in order to select the fields i wish to save LAS2SHP(inFile,outFile=None,parse=None). if None all fields are saved. if **parse** is 
parse="irn" the fields intensity, return_number, and number_of_returns are saved. following the legend

```
"i": p.intensity,
"r": p.return_number,
"n": p.number_of_returns,
"s": p.scan_direction,
"e": p.flightline_edge,
"c": p.classification,
"a": p.scan_angle,
```

I wrote a solution if....ifelse....else really code consuming (and not elegant). Thanks for all helps and suggestions for saving code

thanks in advance
Gianni

here the original function in python

```
import shapefile
from liblas import file as lasfile

def LAS2SHP(inFile,outFile=None):
    w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)
    w.field('Z','C','10')
    w.field('Intensity','C','10')
    w.field('Return','C','10')
    w.field('NumberRet','C','10')
    w.field('ScanDir','C','10')
    w.field('FlightEdge','C','10')
    w.field('Class','C','10')
    w.field('ScanAngle','C','10')
    for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r'):
        w.point(p.x,p.y)
        w.record(float(p.z),float(p.intensity),float(p.return_number),float(p.number_of_returns),float(p.scan_direction),float(p.flightline_edge),float(p.classification),float(p.scan_angle))
    if outFile == None:
        inFile_path, inFile_name_ext = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(inFile))
        inFile_name = os.path.splitext(inFile_name_ext)[0]
        w.save("{0}\\{1}.shp".format(inFile_path,inFile_name))
    else:
        w.save(outFile)
```

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Gianni - it's newish, but you got an answer here so there's no real need to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try something like this:

```
    pdata = [p.z] + [getattr(p, pattr[key]) for key in parse]
    pdata = map(float, pdata)
    w.record(*pdata)
```

- `for key in parse` loops through the letters in `parse`. For example,
  if `parse = 'irn'` then key loops through the values `i`, `r`, `n`.
- `pattr` is a dict. `pattr[key]` is the name of the associated
  attribute. For example, `pattr['i']` is `"intensity"`.
- `getattr(p, pattr[key])` is the value of the `pattr[key]` attribute
  in `p`. For example, `getattr(p, "intensity")` is `p.intensity`. It is the way to get attribute values when you know the name of the attribute as a string, (e.g. `pattr[key]`).
  The `*` in `w.record(*pdata)` unpacks `pdata` before sending the arguments on to `w.record`. For example, `w.record(*[1,2,3])` is equivalent to `w.record(1,2,3)`. It is the way one [sends an arbitrary number of arguments to a function](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/).

---

For example,

```
import shapefile
from liblas import file as lasfile

pattr = {
    "i": 'intensity',
    "r": 'return_number',
    "n": 'number_of_returns',
    "s": 'scan_direction',
    "e": 'flightline_edge',
    "c": 'classification',
    "a": 'scan_angle',
    }

wattr = {
    "i": 'Intensity',
    "r": 'Return',
    "n": 'NumberRet',
    "s": 'ScanDir',
    "e": 'FlightEdge',
    "c": 'Class',
    "a": 'ScanAngle',
    }

def LAS2SHP(inFile, outFile=None, parse = 'irnseca'):
    w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)
    w.field('Z','C','10')
    for key in parse:
        w.field(wattr[key],'C','10')
    for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r'):
        w.point(p.x,p.y)
        pdata = [p.z] + [getattr(p, pattr[key]) for key in parse]
        pdata = map(float, pdata)
        w.record(*pdata)       
    if outFile == None:
        inFile_path, inFile_name_ext = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(inFile))
        inFile_name = os.path.splitext(inFile_name_ext)[0]
        w.save("{0}\\{1}.shp".format(inFile_path,inFile_name))
    else:
        w.save(outFile)
```

Comment: hey Unutbu, thanks. This give me this error message "IndexError: tuple index out of range" using LAS2SHP(inFile="punktsky_1km_6353_561.las",parse="i")

Comment: always the same error IndexError: tuple index out of range :)

Comment: [record.append(recordList[i]) for i in range(fieldCount)] of shapefile module

Comment: Maybe post the entire traceback error message. It would help to see the line of code *in your script* which is ultimately generating the error.

Comment: run the code line-by-line the error is here
>>> w.record(*pdata)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyshp-1.1.4-py2.7.egg\shapefile.py", line 803, in record
    [record.append(recordList[i]) for i in range(fieldCount)]
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Ah, I obviously do not know what shapefile commands do :). I am guessing that we should not be defining `w.field(...)` for fields that will be missing. Editing...

Comment: the problem myabe is here: w.record accepts tuple and not list

Comment: yes works. Good job Unutbu. could i ask the code if i wish only Z? ex: parse = None return only Z values. Thanks always you are really a great programmer

Comment: If you set `parse = ''`, then `for key in parse` will not do anything. So only the `Z` data will get recorded. You can set `parse = ''` as the default value, as in `def LAS2SHP(inFile, outFile = None, parse = ''):` if you wish this to be the default behavior.

Comment: yes i did and works really great. Shapefile module is memory consuming because it stores every points inside the memory and only in the end save the shapefile with "w.save". I had tried to save in streaming but without results and no docs are reported online